# Is there a way to change this BigQuery self-join to use a window function?

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery, window-functions, self-join

Let's say I have a BigQuery table "events" (in reality this is a slow sub-query) that stores the count of events per day, by event type. There are many types of events and most of them don't occur on most days, so there is only a row for day/event type combinations with a non-zero count.

I have a query that returns the count for each event type and day and the count for that event from N days ago, which looks like this:

```
WITH events AS (
  SELECT DATE('2019-06-08') AS day, 'a' AS type, 1 AS count
  UNION ALL SELECT '2019-06-09', 'a', 2
  UNION ALL SELECT '2019-06-10', 'a', 3
  UNION ALL SELECT '2019-06-07', 'b', 4
  UNION ALL SELECT '2019-06-09', 'b', 5
)
SELECT e1.type, e1.day, e1.count, COALESCE(e2.count, 0) AS prev_count
FROM events e1
LEFT JOIN events e2 ON e1.type = e2.type AND e1.day = DATE_ADD(e2.day, INTERVAL 2 DAY) -- LEFT JOIN, because the event may not have occurred at all 2 days ago
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

The query is slow. [BigQuery best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-patterns) recommend using window functions instead of self-joins. Is there a way to do this here? I could use the `LAG` function if there was a row for each day, but there isn't. Can I "pad" it somehow? (There isn't a short list of possible event types. I could of course join to `SELECT DISTINCT type FROM events`, but that probably won't be faster than the self-join.)

Comment: How slow is this?  If you have thousands of days and hundreds of events, then your table is still pretty small.  I would expect the query to be fairly fast.

Comment: In the real application it's not a table, but a sub-query. Edit the question to say that. (I was trying to keep it simple). The entire query takes about 5-6 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, IFNULL(FIRST_VALUE(count) OVER (win), 0) prev_count
FROM `project.dataset.events`
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(day) RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 PRECEDING)
```

If t apply to sample data from your question - result is:

```
Row day         type    count   prev_count   
1   2019-06-08  a       1       0    
2   2019-06-09  a       2       0    
3   2019-06-10  a       3       1    
4   2019-06-07  b       4       0    
5   2019-06-09  b       5       4
```

Answer (score 2):

A brute force method is:

```
select e.*,
       (case when lag(day) over (partition by type order by date) = dateadd(e.day, interval -2 day)
             then lag(cnt) over (partition by type order by date)
             when lag(day, 2) over (partition by type order by date) = dateadd(e.day, interval -2 day)
             then lag(cnt, 2) over (partition by type order by date)
        end) as prev_day2_count
from events e;
```

This works fine for a two day lag.  It gets more cumbersome for longer lags.

EDIT:

A more general form uses window frames.  Unfortunately, these have to be numeric so there is an additional step:

```
select e.*,
       (case when min(day) over (partition by type order by diff range between 2 preceding and current day) = date_add(day, interval -2 day)
             then first_value(cnt) over (partition by type order by diff range between 2 preceding and current day)
        end)
from (select e.*,
             date_diff(day, max(day) over (partition by type), day) as diff   -- day is a bad name for a column because it is a date part
      from events e
     ) e;
```

And duh!  The `case` expression is not necessary:

```
select e.*,
       first_value(cnt) over (partition by type order by diff range between 2 preceding and 2 preceding)
from (select e.*,
             date_diff(day, max(day) over (partition by type), day) as diff   -- day is a bad name for a column because it is a date part
      from events e
     ) e;
```

Comment: That's actually not too bad with lags up to a week or so, slightly modified (see edited question). It is slightly faster than the self-join on the real query, so I'm using it.Thanks!

Comment: @EM0 . . . The final version should be the best solution.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot! It showed the values for 2 days *later* so I had to change `preceding` to `following`. Also the `max(day)` seems unnecessary - it's purpose is just to convert a date to an integer, so it can be a diff from a fixed day, right? I updated the question with the query I ended up using.

Comment: @EM0 . . . The `max(day)` is not necessary.  You can use a fixed date.  The ordering of the arguments is so that `diff` will be positive.

Comment: I have to do `date_diff(day, '1970-01-01', day)` for the diff to be positive and then `range between 2 preceding` works. This is probably more intuitive to read, so I've changed it to that.

Comment: Thanks. I feel a little bad accepting another answer after you've done all the hard work :) but it is the simpler one - turns out there is no need for a sub-query to get the epoch date.